# Summing based on another column

Tags: r, list

I'm trying to find the last value in a column before the value returns to zero. I have a column which has measured the intervals of an event occuring, and I want to subset the last value before a zero. Here is a snippet of the code. (This is a data frame)

```
Phase Duration
1     0
1     1.37
1     2.9
1     3.5
2     0
2     1.09
2     3.92
3     0
3     0.23
4     0
4     0.59
4     0.93
```

So my desired output would be

```
Phase TotalDuration
1     3.5
2     3.92
3     0.23
4     0.93
```

I naively thought that summing the values would work but 0.93 + 0.59 is obviously greater than 0.93

Comment: From your example, the expected output can be got by grouping by 'Phase' and getting the last row for each group, i.e.  `library(dplyr); df1 %>% group_by(Phase) %>% slice(n())`  If this is not what you want, please update the post with a better example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is what you are after

```
dat <- data.frame(Phase=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4),
                  Duration=c(0,1.37,2.9,3.5,0,1.09,3.92,0,0.23,0,0.59,0.93))

library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(Phase) %>%
  summarise(TotalDuration=max(Duration))
```

Output:

```
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

  Phase TotalDuration
  <dbl>         <dbl>
1     1          3.50
2     2          3.92
3     3          0.23
4     4          0.93
```

Answer (score 0):

Several options.

```
dat <- data.frame(
     Phase=c(   1,    1,    1,    1,    2,    2,    2,    3,    3,    4,    4,    4 ),
  Duration=c(   0, 1.37,  2.9,  3.5,    0, 1.09, 3.92,    0, 0.23,    0, 0.59, 0.93 )
)
```

1. From @akrun's comment:

   ```
   library(dplyr)
   dat %>%
     group_by(Phase) %>%
     slice(n())
   # Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
   # Groups: Phase [4]
   #   Phase Duration
   #   <int>    <dbl>
   # 1     1     3.50
   # 2     2     3.92
   # 3     3     0.23
   # 4     4     0.93
   ```
2. Base R, if you can always assume `max` works:

   ```
   aggregate(Duration ~ Phase, data = dat, FUN = max)
   ```
3. Base R, if you cannot assume `max` and should use "last" instead:

   ```
   # optional use of a helper-function ... dplyr::last works too
   last1 <- function(x) tail(x, n = 1)
   aggregate(Duration ~ Phase, data = dat, FUN = last1)
   ```

For future reference, your question is mis-named, and it could stand to have a little more detail:

- at what point do you "sum" anything?
- please include any code you've tried
- if you searched in StackOverflow for anything in R including "[variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+variable+by+group)", the top couple of posts are likely useful.

Comment: When I talked about summing I was explaining how I initially thought that would work but it obviously won't. Thank you, will take everything you've said on board!

Comment: Got it. (What I don't understand is how @Swapnil's answer -- which was submitted after both akrun's answering-comment and my answer, and offers nothing innovative over either one -- was accepted.)